# Can you require all node modules at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Currently, whenever I want to use a module in node.js standard library that is not part of the global objects e.g. `readFileSync()`, I require/import the module which that functionality belongs to, in this example, that's the `fs` module. A list of the global objects is here for reference: (https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

Is there a way to require/import all the node.js standard library, i.e. to have all of the node.js standard library available throughout my program?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? Some packages, like React, for example, need to be imported/required in each '.jsx' file.. If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to use all packages under some global variable? I dont understand how you would even do this in Python... If you need to use `requests`, wouldn't you have to `import requests` in each `.py` file that needs to use it? Same for any package, like `import json`, etc... How does Python come with "batteries included" in this sense?

Comment: @MattOestreich I edited the question - you are right about python imports, I forgot you had to import the libraries you need.

Comment: The `process` module is part of the "standard library" aka built into node... You do NOT have to require `process` in order to use `exit()` - you would just do `process.exit()` from anywhere in your app.......

Comment: @MattOestreich yes, `process.exit()` worked without `require`, which should make things easier for me. Although the same thing didn't work for `fs.readFileSync`. So some of the 'standard library' are globals and some aren't. I found a list of globals in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: @MattOestreich I updated the question again to use the correct terminology.

Comment: This brings me back to our discussion about Python.. I don't understand why you would want to bloat your app by loading all "built-in" modules into RAM when you may or may not even use them.. I do not understand why anyone would possibly want to do what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't require all node modules at once.  There are tens of thousands of possible modules, some built-into node.js and some available only if you install them into your project.  In the interest of modularity, you import into each module the modules that you need inside that module.  This is purposely done this way to make modules be modular so that they declare exactly what they need to import and only what they need to import.

This is a bit different way of thinking than some other environments, but once you get used to it, it works quite well and makes code reuse a lot cleaner and easier.  The start of each module file should import that external modules that you need to use within that module.

Comment: I updated the question to specifically state the node standard library

Comment: @leonsegal - There's still no way to import even all the standard libraries without loading each one individually.  They are pieces of Javascript that have to be loaded and run in order to use them.  I'd really recommend, you just get use to declaring each module's external dependencies with a few `require()` or `import` statements at the top of the module.  It works fine once you get used to it and has numerous benefits.  It really isn't worth it to try to buck the system.  This is how node.js works.  It's how a modular environment works.